# Xcode 8 beta 2 (8S162m) can't archive error 0

Tags: archive, xcode8, xcode8-beta2

[image: The report of "Can't archive Xcode 8 beta 2 (8S162m)]
I download from https://developer.apple.com/download/
My MBPR OSX is 10.11.4

I tried "Archive Utility" & "Unarchiver" and no work both.

Comment: What, exactly, is your question? This seems like an Apple support question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Release Note:Xcode 8 beta 2/3 requires a Mac running macOS version 10.11.5 or later.

Comment: Thanks! I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

If you upgrade to OS X 10.11.5 or higher, the problem goes away.

Comment: Thanks! I fixed it.